How to find journals accepting submissions in literary criticism?
I've been trying to find academic journals looking for submissions, but when I search for literary journals, all I find are journals looking for fiction or poetry submissions, not essays. Additionally, most "calls for papers" lists I find are for conferences, not journals. help?

Where do you read literary criticism? It would be very unusual to be capable of submitting journal-quality work in any field without reading journal-quality work. And yes, "calls for papers" is typically a conference-specific phrase, journals do not typically call for papers in my experience.

Well a quick search turned up the Columbia Journal of Literary Criticism. This is not my field, there may be others as far as I know.

Have you tried searching Scimago or a similar site for "literary criticism" or even just "literary?" Also, I'd imagine that many journals which do cultural studies would be open to literary criticism.
